# Looking for a scoring formula that takes into account how quickly was answered

Tags: functions

I'm not that great at math,  so looking for your help on this one...

The goal is to end up with a formula f(q, t) where q is a value between 0 and 1 inclusive, representing the percentage of correct answers,  and t is the time it took to answer the questions, with a maximum.

The challenge I'm facing is that I want to avoid that a team can enter 1 correct question very quickly and win. the team with more correct answers should always be preferred over others.

I have the feeling this is quite basic but not knowing the right words to google for it, trying my luck here.

thanks!

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

A team gets $q$ right out of $Q$, and takes a time $t$ out of a maximum $T$, should score
$$\frac{q+1-(t/T)}{Q+1}$$

Comment: thank you, this helps!